Cors Issue in VUE JS 3 on API call from Localhost to Third Party API
I have been facing CORS issue form many days. I have applied all the solutions that are available in Stack Overflow, but nothing helpful for me. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong with my code? I am using VUE JS 3 where I am using an API that is hosted on a different server. I tried all headers that can fix but nothing was helpful for me.
ENV URL
 VITE_APP_API_URL="http://localhost:5173" 

vue.config.js: file is placed in root folder.
module.exports = {
     devServer: {
            proxy: 'https://ded.austory.it'
           }
    }

Calling API from here:
function login(credentials: User) {
     // ApiService.setCrossHeaders();
    return ApiService.post("/login", credentials)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setAuth(data);
      })
      .catch(({ response }) => {
        setError(response.data.errors);
      });
  }

Defining the API Service:
 .......
import type { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
  .....

/**
   * @description set the POST HTTP request
   * @param resource: string
   * @param params: AxiosRequestConfig
   * @returns Promise<AxiosResponse>
   */
  public static post(resource: string, params: any): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
    return ApiService.vueInstance.axios.post(`${resource}`, params);
  }

The above code is responsible for making an API call. So what is going wrong I do not know. output is

If I set in env :   VITE_APP_API_URL="https://ded.austory.it" (real site name can't share here.)  then


But there is a catch here, when setting ENV URL
   VITE_APP_API_URL="https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic8/laravel/api" 

after this, No Cors error comes from the localhost. How I do not know? I checked in my project there is no other definition of this URL in a project. hHw it is accepting but mine not?

See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , the question doesn't contain necessary details. "I tried all headers " - this is not constructive, what did you try? Primarily this is the problem of your setup and how you make a request, don't focus the question on Vue, it's UI framework and is irrelevant. The question lacks specifics, you mention VITE_APP_API_URL, so it's supposedly Vite, but use vue.config.js, which is Vue CLI. It's either one or another. If you use Vite indeed, this means vue.config.js is useless, refer Vite docs how to set devserver proxy.

Basically, remote api (ded.austory.it) whitelist the origins (domain+port) that can access it and restrict the rest, this is what cors is about, to prevent unauthorized use. Special headers may be needed for cors request, but if you don't have official access to the api and not whitelisted, no headers will help. Your only option is to proxy the requests through your own server that doesn't have cors restrictions AND make the requests to it instead of remote api. This is what happens with devserver proxy, you run aserver at 1234 port and make reqs to devserver:1234/api/..., not ded.austory.it

Devserver is for dev only, as the name suggests, it's not intended for prod. It's to make cors easier when is server runs on localhost because localhost is rarely allowed by cors. You can use it in prod as a quick workaround, but be aware of security and perf issues. It's unknown how you run things in prod. But if you don't have proper access to the api, you still need to proxy the reqs to avoid cors, through node server, nginx, anything.

My problem was fixed by the target server ( destination server ). I discussed this issue with my network team in my company. they updated the server configuration. so after that, any host can send a request to get data from API.
In Detail, I want to say that my project was on the abc.com server and I was requesting data from the xyz.com server. both hosting was of our company. so that they allow me to request abc.com to xyz.com. we are using the services of xyz.com. so after updating this issue was fixed.
Another thing is that my Front-end UI is Vue JS where partially I am using vite. so for proxy, I was writing the code in vue.config.js that should be written on vite.config.js based on @estus-flask .  So after that, it could not help me any more. I mentioned this code because @estus-flask mentioned that vue.config.js is not relevant. So @estus-flask bro I tried both configurations but nothing helpful..
For vite.config.js we can use a proxy ... For More detail : visit vite doc
.....
server: {
        proxy: {
            '/foo': 'http://localhost:4567',
            '/api': {
                target: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
                changeOrigin: true,
                secure: false,
            },
        },
    },
.....

